# Unable to display xclock on aix

Tags: weblogic, aix, weblogic11g

Im trying to install weblogic on aix, I have installed xmanager and started it in passive mode.

Have set the export DISPLAY=xxxxxxxx:0.0 
and when i do xclock i get the following error :

```
Error: Can't open display: xxxxxxxx:0.0
```

Do we need to check for any other pre-requisites for xclock to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xclock started working fine after we reinstalled the X11 libraries.

Thanks for eveyone's valuable inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/paixperiences/entry/remotex11aix?lang=en) on how to use XWindows on AIX - it involves a few setup procedures and the instillation of a local X Server (Cygwin).

Alternatively if you can't get this method to work OR want to get on with the instillation quicker you could use the WebLogic silent instillation method documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13196_01/platform/docs81/install/silent.html).

Comment: There is step in that which involves to restart the ssh service,
there wasnt any folder structure of sshd_config file, i created the file and added the following


X11Forwarding yes


but when i start the ssh service it says..


# stopsrc -sshd
0513-085 The shd Subsystem is not on file.
#


any suggestions on this?

Comment: After having a quick google for 'The shd subsystem is not on file' most posts suggest reinstalling the openssl library will fix this issue.

Comment: I have reinstalled sshd services and also set the x11forwarding to yes,
bus still get the same error, 
Error: Can't open display:

anything that I can check on ?